# what is the meaning of this statement " (sum => value => sum += value)(0) " and what is it's role here in the below code?

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

This code is used for finding the cumulative sum of an array [5, 10, 3, 3] i.e.

output = [5,15,18,21]

here everything is correct i just want to know the meaning of this line

```
(sum => value => sum += value)(0)
```

anybody who knows this ?

```js
const cumulativeSum = (sum => value => sum += value)(0);

console.log([5, 10, 3, 2].map(cumulativeSum));
```

Comment: Does it make more sense as `sumFn = function (sum) { return function(value) { return sum += value } }; cumulativeSum = sumFn(0)`?

Comment: Are you asking what [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) are?

Comment: [Map with a callback function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#callbackfn)

Comment: @CBroe  yes i want to know the meaning of these , i.e. if we are writing this way (sum => value => sum += value)(0), then what does that mean

Comment: This question shouldn't be closed. The linked question isn't relevant to what OP's asking about.

Comment: He's not asking about arrow functions or calling a function without parameters, he's asking about the way it was curried

Comment: @Brother58697  yes you are right i am not asking about arrow functions , i am asking about the way it is carried furthur

Comment: @KarishmaSingh If the linked answer isn't enough, here's a [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/wirunox/edit?js,console) explaining it with an example.

Comment: @Brother58697 the question is re-opened. you can post your jsbin but do rename c u m to cumulative or cumul to not be flagged by search engines

Comment: @mplungjan Will do, and fair enough haha! :P

Comment: @mplungjan it's still closed on my end

Comment: Shift-reload the browser

Comment: I tried, but it's still taking me either here with the `noredirect` flag which shows it's closed, or auto ridirects to 'What is Currying', even if I try to access it from @KarishmaSingh's account page